# UINavigationController Stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

Apps such as Instapaper and Twitterrific launch to views that aren't the root view of their navigation stacks. We know this because the initial view already has a back button. Instapaper launches one level deep (Instapaper > Read Later) and Twitterific two levels deep (Accounts > Account > All Tweets).

What's the most efficient/recommended way to achieve this behaviour using Storyboards (perhaps `pushViewController:animated:` or `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`) and how does one achieve this whilst taking into account the new state restoration APIs, to reduce the chance of a conflict between the view I want to present and the one the state restoration process wants to present?

Answer (score 1):

You can't initiate a segue via Storyboards only, you'll have to write code. And by writing code I mean you probably want to use `UINavigationController`'s `-setViewControllers:animated:` method, since segues are generally used to make nice animated transitions and not initial UI setup.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I am asking what is the best way to launch to a view that is at least one level deeper than the root view in my navigation stack (in the same way the example apps mentioned do), and how to do this whilst not conflicting with the new state restoration APIs.

Comment: I'd suggest you preserve and restore the `UINavigationController`'s stack up to second VC, and also make it initial view controller in the Storyboard. This way you'll have navigation stack already set up after application launch.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure you're understanding what I'm asking. At launch, I want an navigation controller to automatically jump to the second controller, so that a back button is set up which takes you back to the first controller. I also want to do this in a way that doesn't cause conflict with the new state restoration APIs.

Comment: I gave answers to both of your questions. You clearly do not understand how restoration API works and it looks like you know nothing about `UINavigationController` as well. I'd suggest you go read some documentation before arguing.

Comment: Really? You told me I could not instantiate a segue in a storyboard (not a question I asked) and you told me to make the second view controller the initial view controller, which certainly doesn't achieve what I'm asking. I do understand how the state restoration API works which I why I can see there's potential for conflict. I'll disregard the rest of your comment.

Comment: I am sorry, forgive my rudeness. Not the second VC, `UINavigationController` as initial view controller, which state preservation and restoration will be handled by UIKit automatically. With that in place, there would be no conflict with UI hierarchy and it's stack also will be preserved and restored with all VCs, if VCs on stack have restoration identifiers set. Since all manipulations (like pushing another VC on stack) take place after app launch (and after restoration) it would be wise to check for possible conflicts inside VCs also.

Comment: So I could set a BOOL iVar in `application:didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` which could be used to determine if the view had been restored, and then only push the relevant controller onto the stack in `viewDidLoad` if it hadn't?

Comment: Basically, yes. I would also check if VCs need additional initialisation usually done in `viewDidLoad` depending on if VC has been restored or created anew.

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller is a second one in the hierarchy, I'd simply call `UINavigationController`'s `- (void)pushViewController:animated:` (with `animated:NO`) from its `viewDidLoad` method. If it's deeper, then `- (void)setViewControllers:` instead of push.

Comment: Thanks Rudolf; this is what I first thought, but then wouldn't that conflict with state restoration?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't played with the state restoration yet. Maybe you can check the navigation controller (like what is the top-most controller) from `application:didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and then decide what to do.

Comment: BTW, sorry - I hadn't read your question carefully, that's why I didn't mentioned the state restoration thing. Anyway, great question.